# How can I let stream online keep playing when I switch between activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, stream

I've spent nearly the entire day trying to find a solution for a specific `MediaPlayer` problem, the code below is for my main activity  I'm building an Android app that will stream radio station but when I switch between activity the stream stop, 
How can I let stream online (radio) keep playing when I switch between activities ?

```
package radiofm.arabel;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import static android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ImageButton id_play,id_pause;

    private Button btn;
    private boolean playPause;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean initialStage = true;


    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView=null;
    Toolbar toolbar =null;



    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Log.d("myTag", "This is my toolbar");


        id_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.id_play);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        id_play.setEnabled(true);
        id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        id_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!playPause) {
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

                    if (initialStage) {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is my excute");
                        new Player().execute("http://arabelfm.ice.infomaniak.ch/arabelprodcastfm.mp3");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is my beforestart");

                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            Log.d("myTag", "This is my afterstart");

                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }

                    playPause = true;

                } else {
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    Log.d("myTag", "This is my beforestop");

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is afterstop");

                        mediaPlayer.reset();

                    }

                    playPause = false;
                }
            }
        });




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }



    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Boolean prepared = false;

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is my listnner");
                        initialStage = true;
                        playPause = false;
                        id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
//                Log.e("MyAudioStreamingApp", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
            }

            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            initialStage = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_alarm) {
            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_Alarm.class);
            startActivity(goToNextActivity);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_aaaaa) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Service class to stream when the activity is not in the foreground

Comment: @CoolGuyCG yeah but how to do that ? can u explain more

Comment: Try reading on Android Service class. But you can check my answer below too for a simple way I would have done this

Answer (score 0):

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public MyService() {
            }

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
//You may want to initialise all your stuff here

}

//call these from any context
public void startPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

//You may not need the AsyncTask again so push the relevant code into the service
//This method could be collapsed into startPlayer()
public void executePlayer() {
    new Player().execute("http://arabelfm.ice.infomaniak.ch/arabelprodcastfm.mp3");
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public void reset() {
    mediaPlayer.reset();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

After you have started the service, it will continue running until you decide to kill it so it could be better if all your mediaplayer operations are done here and then you control it with commands from your activity.

Comment: should i delete everything in mainActicity ?

Comment: Not at all. it is up to you although you can do away with the AsyncTask if you moved the mediaplayer stuff into the service

Comment: how to link between my service and other activity? sorry i am begining

Comment: startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);

Comment: where should i write it ? in which activity ?

Comment: If you mean the service, it's best you give it its own  java file, if you mean starting it, then use it in the onClick method of the button you use in starting your mediaplayer